# LDAP SSO with waffle

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-ldap, waffle

I am using a spring 5 web application.

I'm totally new to Waffle
I would like to use waffle for users to authenticate on my web app with their Windows credentials.
Once I get the username, I will do LDAP serach.

But I am not sure where I can write my customize code to fetch username to validate?

I tried with spring security LDAP. But can't get the window user login name.
On net someone suggest to use waffle to fetch window user information

WebSecurityConfig code

```
 @Autowired
public WindowsAuthenticationProvider windowsAuthenticationProvider;

@Autowired
private NegotiateSecurityFilter securityFilter;

@Autowired
private NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;


@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .addFilterBefore(this.securityFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(this.authenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
            .authenticationProvider(windowsAuthenticationProvider) // Set authentication provider here
            .formLogin();
            //.authenticationDetailsSource(waffleAuthenticationDetailsSource);

}

//Waffle Spring Security Beans
@Bean
public WindowsAuthProviderImpl windowsAuthProvider() {
    WindowsAuthProviderImpl waffle = new WindowsAuthProviderImpl();
    return waffle;
}
@Bean
@Autowired
public NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider negotiateSecurityFilterProvider(final WindowsAuthProviderImpl windowsAuthProvider) {

    return new NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider(windowsAuthProvider);
}
@Bean
@Autowired
public SecurityFilterProviderCollection waffleSecurityFilterProviderCollection(final NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider negotiateSecurityFilterProvider) {

    final List<SecurityFilterProvider> securityFilterProviders = new ArrayList<SecurityFilterProvider>();
    securityFilterProviders.add(negotiateSecurityFilterProvider);
    return new SecurityFilterProviderCollection(securityFilterProviders.toArray(new SecurityFilterProvider[]{}));
}
@Bean
@Autowired
public NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint negotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint(final SecurityFilterProviderCollection securityFilterProviderCollection) {
    final NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint negotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint = new NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint();
    negotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint.setProvider(securityFilterProviderCollection);
    return negotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint;
}
@Bean
@Autowired
public NegotiateSecurityFilter waffleNegotiateSecurityFilter(final SecurityFilterProviderCollection securityFilterProviderCollection) {
    final NegotiateSecurityFilter negotiateSecurityFilter = new NegotiateSecurityFilter();
    negotiateSecurityFilter.setProvider(securityFilterProviderCollection);
    return negotiateSecurityFilter;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public WindowsAuthenticationProvider windowsAuthenticationProvider(final WindowsAuthProviderImpl windowsAuthProvider) {

    WindowsAuthenticationProvider provider = new WindowsAuthenticationProvider();

    provider.setAuthProvider(windowsAuthProvider);
    return provider;
}
```

xml

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <custom-filter ref="waffleNegotiateSecurityFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <http-basic />
</http>

<beans:bean id="waffleNegotiateSecurityFilter" class="waffle.spring.NegotiateSecurityFilter">
    <beans:property name="Provider" ref="waffleSecurityFilterProviderCollection" />
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="sunrise.crm.webapp.common.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider">
    <!-- <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" /> -->
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="waffleWindowsAuthProvider" class="waffle.windows.auth.impl.WindowsAuthProviderImpl" />

<beans:bean id="negotiateSecurityFilterProvider" class="waffle.servlet.spi.NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="waffleWindowsAuthProvider" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="basicSecurityFilterProvider" class="waffle.servlet.spi.BasicSecurityFilterProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="waffleWindowsAuthProvider" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="waffleSecurityFilterProviderCollection" class="waffle.servlet.spi.SecurityFilterProviderCollection">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="negotiateSecurityFilterProvider" />               
            <beans:ref bean="basicSecurityFilterProvider" />               
        </beans:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Would you like to user 'waffle' to use Windows Kerberos based SSO or would you just want to use LDAP (against Windows AD) to authenticate users?

If the latter is the case, you don't need waffle.

If the former is the case, why do you need to verify the username? It's already verified by the Kerberos eco system.

Comment: I want to get the window userName to authenticate request . For fetching window username someone suggest to use waffle.

Comment: Windows does not really have 'userName'. If Kerberos is used to authenticate a user, there is the UserPrincipalName (typically something like 'samAccountName@KerberosRealm' -- most of the time it looks like an email address but it's not). 

If LDAP is used for authentication the 'Distinguished Name' together with the password is used for an LDAP bind operation. Spring Security searches the DN based on some search filter. You can define which attribute is used as the 'user name'.

For the sake of simplicity just go with LDAP.